# I can't run my Rails web server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, webserver

I have installed ruby193 and I've installed rails via the command prompt. However, whenever I try the command:

```
ruby script/server
```

I get this error:

```
ruby: No such file or directory -- script/server (LoadError)
```

I checked my script folder and all it has is a file called rails.

I'm very new to Ruby on Rails and I'm not entirely sure if I've installed everything correctly. Is there an easy way to check what I have installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Ruby & rails installed properly, then `ruby -v` would result in the version that you have installed and likewise `rails -v` would give the rails version installed.

To run a rails server try running `rails server` or `rails s`

Answer (score 1):

Try running `rails server` or `rails s`.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify on the existing answers, `ruby script/server` is no longer the proper way to start a server in Rails. In Rails 3, we use `rails server`, which can be shortened to `rails s`. See [the Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-server) for a more extensive rundown of the Rails 3 command line interface.